# Google Drive: get the list of users with whom the file is shared

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have some shared files (Google doc, Google Sheet) with Google Drive, and people can ask for permission to access them.

For example, here is a exemple of google sheet file : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13Wy-kLO22Y6stIzV0CjkAFVx0-EOy5hv26n8uo40xck/edit?usp=sharing

It is shared with several users, and you can ask for permission to access it.

Then I can see the list of all the users and their emails, and I can do copy paste.

Now, my question is: how can I get all the emails in a Excel file (or Google sheet, of course) ?

I think there can be a google app script/google sheet macro, to automate the process ? The idea then is to get the users names and email adresses.

Comment: _some files_ — if there is the way to describe the files somehow? Do they have similar names? Or do they store in the same folder? Or do you have a list of their names or IDs or URLs?

Comment: one simple example can be a google doc. We can create one in google drive, and share it with limited access. Then people who want to access it have to ask for permission

Comment: Let assume that all the shared files will be in the same folder. Then it can be a script that gets all owners/editor of all the files in the special folder and put the list of owners on the table. Is it correct assumption? Can you show how the table should look like?

Comment: Thank you Yuri, I added an example of google sheet file. maybe can click yourself and I will grant access for you to edit.

Comment: You can get emails and names of editors and viewers, but, as far as I can tell, there is no way to get dates when the access was granted. I can be wrong, though.

Comment: Have you tried the suggested solution? Could you please provide feedback?

Comment: I had some trouble to run app script in Google sheet in general. Now it works ! Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's still not clear how you mean to get the files and how the result should look like. Suppose you have the table where column A contains the list of IDs of the files.

| ID | Owner | Editors | Viewers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1kO__q9CTKFeXJZYcp9oHJ0at0_Z |  |  |  |
| 13ROPW5dJwnccidEQ4kYY8k4Wnif |  |  |  |
| ...etc |  |  |  |

This script will obtain email(s) of an owner, editors and viewers for every file with given ID and put these emails in column B, C and D respectively:

```
function get_editors_viewers() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const ids = sheet.getRange('a2:a').getValues().flat().filter(String);
  const table = [];
  
  for (let id of ids) {
    try {
      var file    = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
      var owner   = file.getOwner().getEmail();
      var editors = file.getEditors().map(e => e.getEmail()).join('\n');
      var viewers = file.getViewers().map(v => v.getEmail()).join('\n');
      table.push([id, owner, editors, viewers]);
    } catch(e) {
      table.push([id, '', '', '']);
    }
  }

  sheet.getRange(2,1,table.length,table[0].length).setValues(table);
}
```

The result should be something like this:

| ID | Owner | Editors | Viewers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1kO__q9CTKFeXJZYcp9oHJ0at0_Z | aaa@aaa.aaa | bbb@bbb.bbb | ccc@.ccc.ccc |
| 1PwzEEU9CncV8N0Xh1oe5JYk_t-X | aaa@aaa.aaa |  | ccc@.ccc.ccc |
| 13ROPW5dJwnccidEQ4kYY8k4Wnif | aaa@aaa.aaa | bbb@bbb.bbb |  |
| 1nw5eU4-EpBWAmqy-cv2UR0OWPcS | aaa@aaa.aaa |  |  |
| 1nQfGvAhWeXVQkI1WkCUFMRHCuVl | aaa@aaa.aaa |  | ccc@ccc.ccc bbb@bbb.bbb xxx@xxx.xxx |
| 1jKCdKeasQR_RSNLkTZj9P1V_qTa | aaa@aaa.aaa | ccc@ccc.ccc bbb@bbb.bbb | ccc@ccc.ccc bbb@bbb.bbb xxx@xxx.xxx |
| 10404WvWgX_lanb5OMtjLYm6N9Ia | aaa@aaa.aaa | ccc@ccc.ccc bbb@bbb.bbb |  |

If you have URLs instead of IDs all you need is to change

`var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);`

with

`var file = DriveApp.getFileByUrl(id);`.